# When creating a web widget should i use data attributes on the container div or should i add parameters to the script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, requirejs

I'm creating a web widget. So basically i load a script from a remote server and display content in a container div. I have the need to send extra parameters to the server, for example filter some contents or choose the display and so i have two options

Pass the data in the script tag ( i'm generating the script dinamically in the code )

```
<script src="http://localhost/wordpress/?ai1ec_requirejs_widget&ai1ec=action:posterboard|no_navigation:true|request_type:jsonp"></script>
<div id="timely"></div>
```

Pass the data as data attributes of the `<div>`

```
<script src="http://localhost/wordpress/?ai1ec_requirejs_widget&ai1ec=action:posterboard|no_navigation:true|request_type:jsonp"></script>
<div id="timely" data-action="view" data-no-navigation="true" data-request-type="jsonp" ></div>
```

As of now i've choosen the first approach for this reason: If i include data in the request script i don't have to wait for the DOM to be ready to get the value of the `<div>` to filter events.
 The script i'm loading is just a small script that loads requirejs asynchronously. 
Require js as soon as it has loaded makes an ajax call to fetch data ( no need to wait for the DOM to be ready as i already have all the informations i need )  and when the data arrives, if the dom is ready, it starts attacching event handler. Otherwise i have to wait for the DOM to be Ready before making the call to fetch data

My idea was that if i include

```
<script src="http://localhost/wordpress/?ai1ec_requirejs_widget&ai1ec=action:posterboard|no_navigation:true|request_type:jsonp"></script>
```

as the first script it will start downloading require.js async and then kick off everything much faster, but maybe i'm totally wrong.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

<s>In addition to the concerns you mentioned:</s>

I'd go with passing data in the script tag since that way you have a single point where you configure the widget. Having multiple points of configuration can potentially conflict or be sources of confusion.

Also, it seems like it is the concern of the script to do all the filtering, and not the `div` (since that's a view element), so from that perspective it would also make more sense to have the script handle all that information. This way you're also minimizing the amount of data you're transmitting across the wire. Why load all the information and then filter it on the client-side, when you can do it on the server-side?

**EDIT**

I misunderstood your scenario! I think either way would work, honestly. However, you could minimize the amount of Javascript you write by adding information to the `div` and I think this information is alright since it is semantically appropriate. It would also provide more context to anyone who is reading the code.

Comment: Well of curse i wouldn't load the info to filter them afterwards, i woud take the parameter from the div and then make the call. But to take the parameters from the div i need the DOM to be ready